# htaccess: different url for same page doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've got these lines in htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&article=$2 [NC]
```

when it comes  to address like this `/news/test`, page variable would be like `index.php`.
any idea how to fix that?

Comment: you want all your urls like `http://www.example.com/news/test` or parse as `index.php?page=news&article=test`

Comment: parse as `index.php?page=news&article=test`

Comment: Did my solution worked for you?

Comment: Can you paste exact example like the FULL URLs mentioned by me?

Comment: Your order of URL matching is wrong check my Order carefully. You have to match `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1&article=$2 [NC,L]` first then you have to match `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]` Also you have to add `[L]` to make sure it is last **RULE**

Answer (score 1):

You have `(.*)` matching in **first** row which will match for both your scenarios.

Try this out it worked for me in following scenarios:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1&article=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

It worked for:

```
http://www.example.com/news/test -> http://www.example.com/index.php?page=news&article=test
http://www.example.com/news/ -> http://www.example.com/index.php?page=news&article=
http://www.example.com/news -> http://www.example.com/index.php?page=news
```

Let me know, if you need to do something else. To test it properly i have added `[L,R=302]` instead of `[L]` to see if URL is forming correct or not.

Comment: Tnx for the answer. It still doesn't work. Once i remove

    `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]`
it works for

   ` http://www.example.com/news/test ` and 
    `http://www.example.com/news/ `

but error 404 for

    `http://www.example.com/news` or
   ` http://www.example.com/news/test/`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]` needs to be the last rule cause it matches all entries and make sure to add `[L]` with `[NC,L]` cause it will stop matching further rules else it will keep matching other rules untill last condition it matches.

Comment: Encountering the same errors, i just try to use directive with both parameters, but curious about the reason?! why using both rules make some errors?

Comment: @kaveh The first rule is `^(.*)$` which matches anything after domain name in your case `news/test`.

Comment: Now, if you got it. Will you accept my solution as answer and accept it :)